# postgresql restoring from dumpall file. Indexes and Constraints not being created

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I'm upgrading from and old psql version to a newer (9.5 to 15 (for Ubuntu 20.04)) and when i'm trying to restore from dumpfile everything seems fine except that indexes are not being created.

I made the dumpfile by doing
`pg_dumpall > dbdump.dump`

Then, after upgrading cluster and everything i'm restoring the DB by doing
`psql -f dbdump.dump postgres` as suggested by PostgreSQL Documentation.

When i check indexes with `select * from pg_indexes where tablename not like 'pg%';` there's nothing.

There should be at least 10K+ of indexes (yes, the DB has more than 10K tables, so creating the indexes by hand is not an option)

What could be wrong?

Comment: 1) Where there any errors when you restored? 2) `pg_indexes` is database specific, are you sure you are in the correct database when you run the query. For instance if you are connecting to the  `postgres` (assuming no changes have been made to it) database it will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should check the PostgreSQL log file. If the restore fails, there must be an error in the log file, or even in the console. There are a few more details that would help clarify the situation. For example, are you using a GUI tool for restoring? Or are you running the command from the CLI?